# seeing this error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'keys')"

Tags: reactjs, rxjs, boolean, key, typeerror

Getting a TypeError for this scroll service component. It was working until it was being rendered for another component. Here is the entire code for the scrolling service. The console error is stating "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'keys')"
The ** are pointing to where the console says the error is at.

````
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { Object } from 'prop-types';

export default class ScrollService {
  static scrollHandler = new ScrollService();
  static currentScreenBroadCaster = new Subject();
  static currentScreenFadeIn = new Subject();

  constructor() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.checkCurrentScreenUnderViewport);
  }
  scrollToHireMe = () => {
    let contactMeScreen = document.getElementById('Contact Me');
    if (!contactMeScreen) return;
    contactMeScreen.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
  };
  scrollToHome = () => {
    let homeScreen = document.getElementById('Home');
    if (!homeScreen) return;
    homeScreen.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
  };
  isElementInView = (elem, type) => {
    let rec = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
    let elementTop = rec.top;
    let elementBottom = rec.Bottom;

    let partiallyVisible =
      elementTop < window.innerHeight && elementBottom >= 0;
    let completelyVisible =
      elementTop >= 0 && elementBottom <= window.innerHeight;

    switch(type) {
      case 'partial':
        return partiallyVisible;

      case 'complete':
        return completelyVisible;
      default:
        return false;
    }
  };
  
  ** checkCurrentScreenUnderViewport = (event) => {
    if (!event || Object.keys(event).length < 1) return;
    for (let screen of TOTAL_SCREENS) {
      let screenFromDOM = document.getElementById(screen.screen_name);
      if (!screenFromDOM) continue;**

      let fullyVisible = this.isElementInView(screenFromDOM, 'complete');
      let partiallyVisible = this.isElementInView(screenFromDOM, 'partial');

      if (fullyVisible || partiallyVisible) {
        if (partiallyVisible && !screen.alreadyRendered) {
          ScrollService.currentScreenFadeIn.next({
            fadeInScreen: screen.screen_name,
          });
          screen['alreadyRendered'] = true;
          break;
        }
        if (fullyVisible) {
          ScrollService.currentScreenBroadCaster.next({
            screenInView: screen.screen_name,
          });
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  };
}```
````